# Java: fast way to check if digits in int are in ascending order

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that finds all of the [Armstrong numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) in a range between zero and Integer.MAX_VALUE. Time limit is 10 seconds. I've found that the most time-consuming method is the one that narrows the range of numbers to process by picking only those having their digits in ascending order (with trailing zeros if any). It takes about 57 seconds to run on my machine. Is there any way to make it faster?

```
static boolean isOK(int x)
{
    int prev = 0;

    while(x > 0)
    {
        int digit = x % 10;
        if((digit > prev || digit == 0) && prev != 0) return false;
        x /= 10;
        prev = digit;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method reduces the number of numbers to process from 2.147.483.647 to 140.990.

Comment: Do you want a fast algorithm to test a specific number, or do you just want the total count of such numbers? The latter can be calculated without testing every single number.

Comment: Won't you miss a few that way? (E.g. 153 and 371).

Comment: I need a fast algorithm to list all such numbers. I don't really need to test 153 and 371. They have the same power sums as 135 and 137 which pass this test. Skipping those identical sets of digits is the whole point of this method.

Comment: Of the 88 Armstrong Numbers, the only number that has ascending digits in base 10 (other than the first 10) is: 370. All other Armstrong numbers are non-ascending order.

Comment: @BezObid Then you aren't finding the Armstrong numbers.

Comment: @callyalater Next method takes this method's output, calculates the number's power sum and checks whether this sum is an Armstrong number. Example: this method checks 137 which is OK, next method calculates its power sum which is 371, then calculates 371's power sum which is the same, 371 goes into the list.

Comment: Sounds like there is an opportunity to run your logic in parallel. Whichever algorithm you use, you should get a speed up of X number of cores

Comment: To fast find all those numbers, you should probably make sums of powered digits and find out if they're narcistic numbers. My generalized (signle-threaded) solution of project Euler's problem 30 using this approach takes under a second on a modest computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of sifting through all the ints, just build up the set of numbers with digits in ascending order. I would argue that you probably want a set of strings (and not ints) because it it is easier to build (recursively by appending/ prepending characters) and then later on you need only the individual "digits" for the power test.

[My take on the problem](https://github.com/sorokod/Armstrong), goes to Long.MAX_VALUE (19 digits) in about 6 seconds and all the way to 39 digits in about an hour

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to construct the set of Armstrong numbers one by one and count them instead of checking every number to see whether it's an Armstrong number or not.

In constructing the whole set, note that when you choose each digit, the set of digits you can choose for the next position is determined, and so on. Two alternatives to implement such a method are recursion and backtracking (which is basically a cheaper way to implement recursion).
This method will not need the use of time-consuming division and remainder operations.

Answer (score 0):

You perform two divisions. Divisions are slower than multiplications. So is there a way to change a division into a multiplication? Well... yes, there is.

```
public static boolean isArmstrongNumber(int n) {
  int prev = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    int quotient = n / 10;
    int digit = n - (quotient * 10);
    if ((digit > prev || digit == 0) && prev != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    n = quotient;
    prev = digit;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `n` instead of `x` for `int quotient = x / 10`?

Comment: Thanks, but this way is even slower:) (by a couple %). Double checked.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little optimisable code here. It is likely that your time issue is elsewhere. However, one technique comes to mind and that is [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

```
static Set<Integer> oks = new HashSet<>();

static boolean isOK(int x) {
    if (!oks.contains(x)) {
        int prev = 0;

        while (x > 0) {
            int digit = x % 10;
            if ((digit > prev || digit == 0) && prev != 0) {
                return false;
            }
            x /= 10;
            prev = digit;
        }
        // This one is OK.
        oks.add(x);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This trick uses a `Set` to remember all of the ok numbers so you don't need to check them. You could also keep a `Set` of those that failed too to avoid checking them again but keeping all integers in a collection is likely to break something.

Comment: Isn't the OP just checking each integer only once anyway?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou - I thought that at first but if that were so this routine would not take `57` seconds - or would it - hmmm. Full sweep from `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` took `14` seconds on my system.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou Yep, I am.
My machine is rather on the slow side. But 14 seconds is still not fast enough.

Comment: @BezObid - I suspect you must therefore find an algorithm change to fix your issue. Find a way to not call this method so often. Consider what it means if this method returns `false`, how many numbers could you skip if you get a `false`?

Comment: Are you allowed to cheat by parallelizing?

Comment: @ Klitos Kyriacou Nope

Comment: Oh well. Perhaps instead of sifting through all the ints, just build up the set of numbers with digits in ascending order. I would argue that you probably want a set of strings (and not ints) because it it is easier to build (recursively by appending/ prepending characters) and then later on you need only the individual "digits" for the power test.

Comment: @David Soroko - That is a great idea! Thank you. Now the result is under 400ms and my code passed the test. I can't find a way to mark your comment as correct, I guess you should make it an answer.

Comment: Done :-)  

Is the idea to look only at the "representatives" (e.g. for all permutations of numbers with the same set of digits look only at the one in an ascending order) yours?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Googled it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code doesn't deal with trailing zeroes but is worth checking if it looks promising in terms of performance.

```
static boolean isOK(int x) {
    if (x < 10) {
        return true;
    }

    String xs = Integer.toString(x);
    for (int i = 1; i < xs.length(); i++) {
        if (xs.charAt(i) < xs.charAt(i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That was my first option and it's very slow (over 4 min).

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs x4 as fast as the original (3 sec. on my laptop) and prints `140990 in 3 sec.`
The method `isOK` is unchanged

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean isOK(int x) {
        int prev = 0;
        while (x > 0) {
            int digit = x % 10;
            if (prev != 0 && (digit > prev || digit == 0)) return false;
            x /= 10;
            prev = digit;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Set<Integer> candidates = IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .parallel()
                .filter(n -> isOK(n))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        System.err.printf("%d in %d sec.", candidates.size(), stop / 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been asked on the MIU test, unfortunately, I was not able to solve it, I later worked on it and it worked fine.

```
static int isAscending(int n){
    int rem, rem1, pval = 0; boolean isAsc = true;

    while(n != 0){
        rem = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        rem1 = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        if(rem > rem1){
            continue;
        } else {
            isAsc = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isAsc == true){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```